# Вопрос по работе foreach в php

Tags: php, foreach

Есть цикл for:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($passengers); $i++) {
        $passenger[] = [
            'id' => $passengers[$i]['id'],
            'first_name' => $passengers[$i]['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $passengers[$i]['last_name'],
            'birth_date' => $passengers[$i]['birth_date'],
            'document_number' => $passengers[$i]['document_number'],
            'place_from' => $passengers[$i]['place_from'],
            'flace_back' => $passengers[$i]['flace_back']
        ];
}
```

Он перебирает массив $passengers, состоящий из двух массивов и записывает нужные данные в $passenger.
Если выведем, получается такой результат: (данные ниже в json).

```
[
{
    "id": "11",
    "first_name": "Ivan",
    "last_name": "Ivanov",
    "birth_date": "1990-02-20",
    "document_number": "1234567890",
    "place_from": null,
    "flace_back": null
},
{
    "id": "12",
    "first_name": "Ivan",
    "last_name": "Gorbunov",
    "birth_date": "1990-03-20",
    "document_number": "1224567890",
    "place_from": null,
    "flace_back": null
}
]
```

Массив перезаписывается для того, чтобы отсеять ненужные поля, пришедшие из базы.

Вопрос: Как добиться такого же эффекта через foreach? И вообще можно ли?

Я пробовал так:

```
foreach($passengers as $passenger) {
    $passenger = [
        'id' => $passenger['id'],
        'first_name' => $passenger['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $passenger['last_name'],
        'birth_date' => $passenger['birth_date'],
        'document_number' => $passenger['document_number'],
        'place_from' => $passenger['place_from'],
        'flace_back' => $passenger['flace_back']
    ];
}
```

Но тут в итоге записывается только последний пассажир и выводит:

```
{
"id": "12",
"first_name": "Ivan",
"last_name": "Gorbunov",
"birth_date": "1990-03-20",
"document_number": "1224567890",
"place_from": null,
"flace_back": null
}
```

Что в принципе логично. Но вот только как добиться первого результата через foreach?

Пробовал также добавлять скобы в фориче [] как в for, вот:

```
foreach($passengers as $passenger) {
    $passenger**[]** = [
        'id' => $passenger['id'],
        'first_name' => $passenger['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $passenger['last_name'],
        'birth_date' => $passenger['birth_date'],
        'document_number' => $passenger['document_number'],
        'place_from' => $passenger['place_from'],
        'flace_back' => $passenger['flace_back']
    ];
}
```

Но выводится вообще абра-кадабра:

```
{
"id": "12",
"booking_id": "10",
"first_name": "Ivan",
"last_name": "Gorbunov",
"birth_date": "1990-03-20",
"document_number": "1224567890",
"place_from": null,
"place_back": null,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"0": {
    "id": "12",
    "first_name": "Ivan",
    "last_name": "Gorbunov",
    "birth_date": "1990-03-20",
    "document_number": "1224567890",
    "place_from": null,
    "flace_back": null
}
```

}

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Делайте так же, как и при `for`, т.е. `$passenger[] = ...` Тут вы пропустили квадратные скобки. А вообще, не смотря на то, что можно так вставлять новые элементы в массив, лучше использовать `array_push` (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php). Тогда видно что сейчас именно вставляется что-то в массив

Comment: `Массив перезаписывается для того, чтобы отсеять ненужные поля, пришедшие из базы.` -  а какие? а нельзя из БД сразу доставать нужные поля? А почему нет? А чем мешают другие поля при работе с массивом?

Comment: @СергейМишин Я пробовал скобки добавлять, забыл про это сказать. Правил вопрос, посмотрите в конце. Выводится совсем не то, что нужно почему-то.
Просто дело в том, что я пишу Rest Api на php. И по тз у меня при запросе есть четко прописанное тело ответа, в котором нет места ненужным полям) Вот и переписываю поэтому пришедший массив , но уже без этих полей

Comment: А, понял. почему так. Потому что `foreach($passengers as $passenger) {
    $passenger[] = [` - тут получается вы объявляете в цикле переменную и сразу её используете (`$passenger`). Попробуйте до цикла объявить переменную `$filteredPassengeres = [];` и уже в неё складировать данные. Заодно для других программистов эта переменная даст понять по названию, что она отличается от исходной и там другие данные

Comment: @СергейМишин Именно! Заработало!))

Comment: > чтобы отсеять ненужные поля, пришедшие из базы. сразу в запросе и перечислить только нужные поля

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать ссылку ([&](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)) на элемент массива, чтобы записать его:

```
foreach($passengers as &$passenger) {
    $passenger = [
        'id' => $passenger['id'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Если вам нужно оставить в элементах только определённые ключи, можно явно их указать и использовать [array_filter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0mKb51ofuAhVO-yoKHUK5CD0QFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.array-filter.php&usg=AOvVaw364tp3MZftD6klToTBPGDD):

```
$public_keys = [
    'id',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'birth_date',
    'document_number',
    'place_from',
    'flace_back',
];

foreach ($passengers as &$passenger) {
    $passenger = array_filter($passenger, function ($key) use ($public_keys) {
        return in_array($key, $public_keys);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

Как подсказали в комментариях, «правильнее» вместо ссылок перед циклом определить новый массив и записывать значения уже в него:

```
$public_keys = [
    'id',
    ...
];

$filtered_passengers = [];

foreach ($passengers as $passenger) {
    $filtered_passengers[] = array_filter($passenger, function ($key) use ($public_keys) {
        return in_array($key, $public_keys);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

И дальше использовать уже `$filtered_passengers`

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал использовать ссылки. Потому что это некультурно)) Изменять исходный массив - неправильно))

Comment: Ага, спасибо, дополнил

Comment: @Michael до цикла $filtered_passengers = []; не обязательно объявлять) она и сразу в цикле норм работает

Comment: В целом, ответ больше вредный, чем полезный. Автор вопроса не понимает как работают массивы в пхп. Пичкать его при этом синтаксическим сахаром - только во вред. Куда полезнее было бы объяснить, как добавлять элементы в массив. Сахар надо добавлять только после того, когда уже твердо выучил, как работает базовый код. А так он просто выучит как попугай слово array filter, но не будет понимать его смысла

Comment: @Dmitry_allread_return всегда лучше объявить явно переменную, иначе откуда вы знаете, что до цикла это пустой массив?

Comment: Ссылки можно использовать если знать когда и где, в этом нет ничего некультурного если пользователь функции об этом уведомлён.